# SwiftUI how do I use .textFieldStyle(.myTextFieldStyle) instead of textFieldStyle(MyTextFieldStyle())

Tags: swiftui

Apologies for the title.

I don't know how to word this question properly because I have trouble finding what this is called.

Please allow me to ask this question using examples instead...

Basically I want to turn this:

```
struct MyTextField: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Label")
            TextField("", text: .constant(""), axis: .vertical)
                .textFieldStyle(MyTextFieldStyle())
            
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct MyTextFieldStyle: TextFieldStyle {
    func _body(configuration: TextField<Self._Label>) -> some View {
        configuration
            .padding()
            .overlay {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5, style: .continuous)
                    .stroke(.secondary, lineWidth: 1)
            }
    }
}
```

Into this:

```
struct MyTextField: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Label")
            TextField("", text: .constant(""), axis: .vertical)
                .textFieldStyle(.myTextFieldStyle)
            
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct MyTextFieldStyle: TextFieldStyle {
    func _body(configuration: TextField<Self._Label>) -> some View {
        configuration
            .padding()
            .overlay {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5, style: .continuous)
                    .stroke(.secondary, lineWidth: 1)
            }
    }
}
```

Note that the only difference is

```
.textFieldStyle(MyTextFieldStyle())

vs

.textFieldStyle(.myTextFieldStyle)
```

I thought I could achieve this using an extension to TextField but it didn't seem to work:

```
extension TextField {
    var caviaTextFieldStyle: CaviaTextFieldStyle {
        .init()
    }
}
```

----- answered -----

So the solution is:

```
extension TextFieldStyle where Self == MyTextFieldStyle {
    static var myTextFieldStyle: MyTextFieldStyle {
        .init()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `.memberName` as a value accesses a `static` field of the inferred type. Since `.textFieldStyle()` expects a `TextFieldStyle`, try extending with a `static` member.

```
extension TextFieldStyle {
    static var myTextFieldStyle {
        return MyTextFieldStyle()
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks! Note that a self constraint is required. i.e. extension TextFieldStyle where Self == MyTextFieldStyle